# Intellij Plugin Completion exits on dot?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

**What I wanna achieve?**

When the Completion list shows up, my code will map all the language files located in .neon files and show them as auto complete text.

**What I have done?**

I restricted the completion to only show up when your caret is in between double quotes or single quotes

**Issue**

When I start typing it works as expected

[image]

But as soon as I type the dot character it miss behaves
[image]

I need the completion list to look up my whole string I wrote, not only those after the dot character

As a really bad workaround is to don't write the dot character

[image]

Can it be done somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it. This is a default behavior of intelliJ where i was testing it.
After opening and testing the plugin in a proper intelliJ Ultimate instance. It works by default. I don't know why the sandboxed version has porblems with it.